# How to create a POST request with wininet in C++

Tags: c++, post, wininet

The goal of my C++ code is to send HTTP POST content to a PHP page which will write the content in a file.
I tested my PHP code with a Postman request and it works.

The problem is when I use a C++ client to send my POST message, I the message is not saved so it means the POST request is malformed. This is the code :

```
void sendHello()
{
    LPCSTR header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    char lpb[1000] = "message=Hello I am here !";
    LPVOID myMessage = (LPVOID)lpb;
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, "127.0.0.1", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest  = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "POST", "/message.php", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, header, strlen(header), myMessage, sizeof(myMessage));
}
```

**Answer :**

```
void sendHello()
{
    LPCSTR header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    std::string dataStr = "message=The content of the message !";
    LPVOID myMessage = (LPVOID)dataStr.c_str();
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, "127.0.0.1", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest  = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "POST", "/message.php", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, header, strlen(header), myMessage, myMessage.size());
}
```

Comment: Effectively is strange, the output of sizeof(myMessage) is 4.

Comment: Your "Answer" should have been posted as a real answer, not as an edit to your question. [You can answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(myMessage)` is just the size of a pointer. It's not the size of your message. Don't use `sizeof` unless you *really* are sure of what you're doing.

Since you're in C++, get rid of those ghastly `char` arrays and make yourself a nice `std::string` instead. Then it's easy to find out how long the data is.

Alternatively, `strlen` can help you here without further modification. You're already using it for `header`.

Also, you are not doing any error checking on the results of any of those WinInet functions. That is very bad.